# How can I access object property within this nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, object, drupal-7

```
Array (
    [und] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [tid] => 37
            [taxonomy_term] => stdClass Object (
                [tid] => 37
                [vid] => 9
                [name] => $10 - $20
                **[description] => $10 - $20**
                [format] => filtered_html
                [weight] => 1
                [vocabulary_machine_name] => prices
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Been trying things like this:

```
print $node->field_price['und']['0']['tid']->taxonomy_term;
```

It's like a nested array with an object in there too..I'm not really sure how to get the [description] property that seems to be within the object in there.

Any help? Please!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $node->field_price['und'][0]['taxonomy_term']->description;
```

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\themes\simple7\node.tpl.php on line 24

Comment: Are you sure what you provided in the question was the output of `var_dump($node);`?

Comment: print_r($node->field_price);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print $node->field_price[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['taxonomy_term']->description;
```

LANGUAGE_NONE is the constant which has the 'key' name for the undefined languages and used across Drupal.